# Restart transition effect using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm making a game that uses transitions that are similar to those in 2048. In 2048, when a player spam clicks fast, previous transitions will all end and then the new ones start.

```js
function a(){
  //do this without any transition
  document.getElementById("di").style.width = "100px";
  //do this with transition
  document.getElementById("di").style.width = "300px";
  //goal: every click, reset the width without any transition and start again, without timeouts
}
```

```css
#di {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 10s;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="qwe" onclick="a()">Start</h1>

<div id="di"></div>
```

The  comments in the function a() tell you what i want. basically, i want the rectangle to go back to 100px (instantly) and then start the transition again.

I do not want any timeouts because the real scenario is quite a bit more complicated and cant have delays

also, I know about css animations, but in the real scenario, they won't work

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EyRroJ JS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if using jQuery,

```
function a()
{
   $("#di").css("width", "100px");
   $("#di").animate({width: "300px"});
}
```

and without `transition` property in CSS.

Comment: hmm... ill try it out. prob will work, but might require some work. ty tho